# Black screen after installation of Nvidia driver

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary-drivers

```
$ uname -r
4.1.3-200.fc22.x86_64
```

This is the latest kernel available at the stable repository. Now I want to install the Nvidia drivers for my GTS430 from the rpmfusion repository. I followed the steps described [here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2014/fedora-20-nvidia-guide/).

Instal akmods and dependencies. Because I want to install Steam I include the i686 version of the Xorg libs.

```
# yum install akmod-nvidia xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-libs.i686 kernel-devel acpid
```

Backup old initramfs nouveau image

```
# mv /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r)-nouveau.img
```

Create new initramfs image

```
# dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

After rebooting I only see a black screen instead of the login. I can login to a text shell using `Ctrl+Alt+F2` Here's the content of the Xorg.log file. (I cutted out the VESA mode detection stuff)

```
[    12.105] 
X.Org X Server 1.17.2
Release Date: 2015-06-16
[    12.105] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    12.105] Build Operating System:  4.0.4-202.fc21.x86_64 
[    12.105] Current Operating System: Linux noir.desktop.fedora 4.1.3-200.fc22.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 22 19:51:58 UTC 2015 x86_64
[    12.105] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.1.3-200.fc22.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora_noir-root ro rd.luks.uuid=luks-3915ee81-88ce-455c-a338-ebb5ffc4af48 rd.lvm.lv=fedora_noir/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora_noir/swap rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau video=vesa:off
[    12.105] Build Date: 15 July 2015  08:16:41AM
[    12.105] Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.17.2-2.fc22 
[    12.105] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
[    12.105]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    12.105] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    12.105] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Aug  1 12:39:09 2015
[    12.108] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    12.108] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    12.110] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    12.110] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    12.110] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    12.110] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    12.112] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    12.112] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    12.112] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    12.112] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    12.112] (==) FontPath set to:
    catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d,
    built-ins
[    12.112] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib64/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
[    12.112] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    12.112] (II) Loader magic: 0x81be00
[    12.112] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    12.112]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    12.112]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
[    12.112]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.1
[    12.112]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    12.118] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 1165 does not belong to any known session
[    12.120] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1245:1458:3523 rev 161, Mem @ 0xf8000000/33554432, 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xdc000000/67108864, I/O @ 0x0000df00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    12.121] (WW) "glamoregl" will not be loaded unless you've specified it to be loaded elsewhere.
[    12.121] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    12.121] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    12.121] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/nvidia/xorg/libglx.so
[    12.343] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    12.343]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.343]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    12.344] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  352.30  Tue Jul 21 18:22:32 PDT 2015
[    12.346] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[    12.346] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 1
[    12.346] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    12.346] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    12.346] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 4
[    12.346] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    12.346] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    12.350] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    12.356] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.356]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.0.11
[    12.356]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.356]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.356] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    12.357] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    12.357] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    12.357] (II) Unloading nv
[    12.357] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    12.357] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    12.357] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    12.358] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.358]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
[    12.358]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.358]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.358] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    12.359] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    12.359] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.359]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    12.359]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.359]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.359] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    12.359] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    12.360] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.360]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    12.360]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    12.360]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.360] (II) NOUVEAU driver 
[    12.360] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    12.360]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    12.360]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    12.360]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    12.360]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    12.360]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    12.360]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    12.360]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    12.361]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    12.361]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    12.361]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    12.361]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    12.361]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    12.361]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    12.361] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    12.361] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    12.361] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    12.361] (++) using VT number 1

[    12.365] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled
[    12.365] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    12.365] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    12.366] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    12.366] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    12.366] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    12.366] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    12.366] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.366]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    12.366]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.366] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    12.366] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    12.366] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    12.366] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    12.367] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    12.367] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.367]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    12.367]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.367] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    12.367] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    12.367] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    12.367] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    12.367] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    12.367] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[    12.367] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    12.367] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    12.367] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    12.368] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.368]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.1.0
[    12.368]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.368] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    12.368] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    12.368] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    12.370] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.370]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.370]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.370] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    12.373] (II) VESA(0): Bad V_BIOS checksum
[    12.373] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 14336 kB
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 112.38
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: GF106B Board - 1245sd30
[    12.425] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
[    12.525] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    12.525] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    12.525] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[    12.525] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    12.525] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    12.525] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[    12.525] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[    12.525] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[    12.526] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[    12.526] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level 2
[    12.526] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 1 sec.
[    12.562] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read successfully
[... SNIP ...]
[    12.617] (II) VESA(0): Total Memory: 224 64KB banks (14336kB)
[    12.617] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 30.00-83.00 kHz
[    12.617] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 49.00-61.00 Hz
[    12.617] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using maximum pixel clock of 175.00 MHz
[    12.617] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[    12.618] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "1280x800" (no mode of this name)
[    12.619] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x400" (no mode of this name)
[    12.619] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x400" (no mode of this name)
[    12.619] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x240" (no mode of this name)
[    12.619] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "320x200" (no mode of this name)
[    12.619] (--) VESA(0): Virtual size is 1600x1200 (pitch 1600)
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1600x1200"
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1280x1024"
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "1024x768"
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "800x600"
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): *Built-in mode "640x480"
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): Display dimensions: (520, 320) mm
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): DPI set to (78, 95)
[    12.619] (**) VESA(0): Using "Shadow Framebuffer"
[    12.619] (II) Loading sub module "shadow"
[    12.619] (II) LoadModule: "shadow"
[    12.620] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libshadow.so
[    12.621] (II) Module shadow: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.621]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.1.0
[    12.621]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    12.621] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    12.621] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    12.621] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    12.623] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.623]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.623]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    12.624] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    12.624] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    12.624] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    12.624] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    12.624] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.624]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    12.624]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    12.624] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    12.626] (II) VESA(0): Bad V_BIOS checksum
[    12.626] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 14336 kB
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 112.38
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: GF106B Board - 1245sd30
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
[    12.678] (II) VESA(0): virtual address = 0x7fca695fd000,
    physical address = 0xdd000000, size = 14680064
[    12.699] (II) VESA(0): Setting up VESA Mode 0x14A (1600x1200)
[    12.817] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    12.824] (==) VESA(0): Backing store enabled
[    12.826] (==) VESA(0): DPMS enabled
[    12.826] (==) RandR enabled
[    12.834] (II) SELinux: Disabled by boolean
[    12.839] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[    12.930] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    12.930] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    12.930] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    12.930] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    12.930] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    12.930] (II) Loading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    12.937] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    12.937]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.11.0
[    12.937]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    12.937]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 21.1
[    12.937] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    12.937] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    12.937] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    12.937] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    12.937] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[    12.953] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    12.953] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    12.953] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    12.954] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    12.954] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[    12.955] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    12.955] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    12.955] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    12.955] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    12.955] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    12.955] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    12.955] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    12.956] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    12.956] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    12.968] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    12.968] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    12.968] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    12.968] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    12.968] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[    12.969] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[    12.969] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    12.969] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    12.969] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[    12.969] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    12.969] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    12.969] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[    12.969] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    12.969] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    12.970] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event16)
[    12.970] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    12.970] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    12.970] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Lachesis (/dev/input/event2)
[    12.970] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    12.970] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    12.970] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Razer Razer Lachesis'
[    12.970] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: always reports core events
[    12.970] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    13.021] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    13.021] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[    13.058] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.0/0003:1532:000C.0001/input/input3/event2"
[    13.058] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Razer Razer Lachesis" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[    13.059] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    13.059] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    13.059] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    13.059] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    13.110] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    13.110] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event2 is a pointer caps
[    13.110] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Lachesis (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    13.110] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.110] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.111] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Razer Razer Lachesis (/dev/input/event3)
[    13.111] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.111] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    13.111] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    13.111] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Razer Razer Lachesis'
[    13.111] (**) Razer Razer Lachesis: always reports core events
[    13.111] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    13.111] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    13.111] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    13.151] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb6/6-2/6-2:1.1/0003:1532:000C.0002/input/input4/event3"
[    13.151] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Razer Razer Lachesis" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    13.151] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.151] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    13.151] (II) input device 'Razer Razer Lachesis', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[    13.152] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out Front (/dev/input/event9)
[    13.152] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.152] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.152] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event10)
[    13.152] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.152] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.152] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event11)
[    13.152] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.152] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.152] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out Side (/dev/input/event12)
[    13.152] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.152] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.153] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Rear Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    13.153] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.153] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.153] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Front Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    13.153] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.153] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.153] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line (/dev/input/event8)
[    13.153] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.153] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    13.154] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[    13.154] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.154] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    13.154] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    13.154] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse'
[    13.154] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: always reports core events
[    13.154] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    13.154] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    13.154] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    13.193] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb9/9-4/9-4:1.0/0003:04B4:0101.0003/input/input5/event4"
[    13.193] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    13.193] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.193] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    13.193] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[    13.194] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse (/dev/input/event5)
[    13.194] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    13.194] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    13.194] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    13.194] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    13.194] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    13.194] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse'
[    13.194] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: always reports core events
[    13.194] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    13.194] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    13.194] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event5 is a pointer caps
[    13.194] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    13.235] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb9/9-4/9-4:1.1/0003:04B4:0101.0004/input/input6/event5"
[    13.235] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[    13.235] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    13.235] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    13.235] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    13.235] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    13.235] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    13.235] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event5 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    13.236] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event5 is a pointer caps
[    13.236] (II) input device 'Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse', /dev/input/event5 is a keyboard
[    13.236] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    13.236] (**) Cypress Cypress USB Keyboard / PS2 Mouse: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[    13.236] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    13.236] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
```

I know that the driver was working for this setup with an earlier kernel version (Something around 4.0.X).Is this a software compatibility problem or am I missing something?